# bcp with format file using command dos in windows

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'am trying to import data into sql server table from a file using a format file.

In fact I have 2 databases: a production database and a local database

I want to insert some row of the table shipper of the production database in the local one. The table shipper don't have neither the same columns nor the same order of column in the 2 databases.

That's why I used a file format to do my bcp.

I generate file containing the rows I want to insert in my local database with the following commande

```
bcp "SELECT  shipper_id,Shipper_name FROM ProductionDatabase.dbo.shipper where shipper_id >5" queryout shipper.txt -c -T
```

It works !!

I generate then the format file with the schema of my local table with the following commande

```
bcp LocalDatabase.dbo.shipper nul -T -n -f shipper-n.fmt
```

It works !!

Unfortunately when I tried to insert the file data in my local table 
with the following commande:

```
bcp LocalDatabase.dbo.shipper in shipper.txt -T -f shipper-n.fmt
```

it generates the following error (translated from french)

Can anyone know what is the problem and how can I get arround it.

Thanks in advance

```
unexpected end of file encountered in the bcp data file
```

Comment: If you exported the data in character format (-c) you should use that also for the import -- or if you really need it, you have to check that it matches your file

Comment: Thanks James, the import works but now I have strange values (integer instead of varchar) in shipper_name column like 5525076 instead od DHL. Do you know why? thanks

Comment: It's been years since I used the format files, but you could also check that it has correct separators, data types etc. so that it would match the file contents

Answer (score 0):

Your format file does not match the data. You are exporting using text using `-c`

```
bcp "SELECT  shipper_id,Shipper_name FROM ProductionDatabase.dbo.shipper where shipper_id >5" queryout shipper.txt -c -T
```

But your format file is made for native (binary) data using `-n`

```
bcp LocalDatabase.dbo.shipper nul -T -n -f shipper-n.fmt
```

Either export both as native (my recommendation), or both as text. To prevent this error, export the data file and the format file at the same time, simply add `-f shipper.fmt` to your export

Text version:

```
bcp "SELECT  shipper_id,Shipper_name FROM ProductionDatabase.dbo.shipper where shipper_id >5" queryout shipper.txt -c -T -f shipper.fmt
```

or

Native Version:

```
bcp "SELECT  shipper_id,Shipper_name FROM ProductionDatabase.dbo.shipper where shipper_id >5" queryout shipper.txt -n -T -f shipper.fmt
```

PS. Since you can run into scenarios where your record or row delimiters exist in the data you should pick a character sequence that does not exist in your data as a separator for instance `-t"\t|\t"` (Tab-Pipe-Tab) for fields and `-r"\t|\n"` (Tab-Pipe-Newline) for rows. If you combine the format statement with the export the data and the format file will match and you have the freedom to change the separators on a single command line.

Specify separators after the `-n` or `-c` on the command line