# Generating format file with bcp queryout

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, bcp

I am trying to generate a format file using BCP along with queryout parameter. Below is my query for reference

```
bcp "select * from servername.schema.tablename" queryout D:\temp\bcp\decisionstatus.data -T -S "AHS-LP-203" -N -f D:\temp\bcp\format.fmt
```

Below is the error that I am facing after running above query.

[image]

More details (failed trying):

- [Tried as per Japer's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32570308/3368010)
- [And this as well](https://sqlwithmanoj.com/tag/bcp-queryout/)

Comment: So either the format file isn’t in that location or the service account doesn’t have access to that drive. Collation is an odd error here but you may need to specify it in your select.

Comment: You're trying to _create_ a format file? Your command line doesn't look much like the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/create-a-format-file-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I am able to create a format file by using this command "bcp "servername.schema.table" format nul -c -t, -S "server" -T -f D:\temp\bcp\decisionstatusformat.fmt" but I need to create format file at the time of queryingout data.

Comment: You cannot do this using one bcp call, split it in two: queryout e format. Similar, you cannot load the data to and from server in one bcp call

Comment: It would be great to generate format file while fetching data :( or else editing format file as per the custom query is kindof mess

Comment: If you use Native format and the target fields (or a view) match then you don't need a format file. I never use a format file - only native format